# does the one thread kill the other in a iphone application( both thread are main thread)?

Tags: iphone, nsthread

HI  guys,

==>in my application i have used **three different** thread  code for  one of them is here  all  thread are of  same kind
==>i have defined two thread in appdelegate class 
==>one in the root view controller
==>all the thread having different sleep time

**My question is that does any thread may get killed by the other and the invocation time for one thread get affected by the other?**

```
-(void)PostData
{
NSAutoreleasePool *apool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];// we are responsible for the memory pool

while(TRUE)
{       
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(PostAllthedata) 
                           withObject:nil 
                        waitUntilDone:YES]; 
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:150]; 

}
[apool release];
}

-(void)PostAllthedata
{
PostSyncData *objPostSyncData=[[PostSyncData alloc]init];
[objPostSyncData release];    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Apple reference documents](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html) on the use of the method `- (void)performSelectorOnMainThread:(SEL)aSelector  withObject:(id)arg waitUntilDone:(BOOL)wait` states

> Multiple calls to this method from the
>   same thread cause the corresponding
>   selectors to be queued and performed
>   in the same same order in which the
>   calls were made.

Comment: actually in my application two thread are getting invoked  after the sleep time but one is not getting invoke what can be the reason?

Comment: If the two methods use the main thread at the same time, I think one of them is added to the queue

Comment: actually it is working as i have decrease the sleep time for the  tread which was not getting invocked   but i can not  find the actual  reason behind the thread was not getting invoked Thank u for answering

Comment: @nikhil did u find that answer

Comment: @nikhil actually in my application two thread are getting invoked after the sleep time but one is not getting invoke what can be the reason? –this is my question.did u find the answer for this

Comment: @vijay :you need to give less invocation time for both thread  and though it is not working please put you code snippet here or anywhere for to check

Comment: @nikhil i didn't have any code about to paste.i had read ur problem .it got interesting me.so that i came to know about this from u.whats ur two thread timings.why did they not run before that.any reason.then please explain